# how to count negative and positive numbers in each set from a list?

Tags: python

I have list which contains 30 numbers

```
list = [-21,-22,-33,-55,-454,65,48,-516,614,6,2,-64,-64,-87,6,45,87,15,11,03,-34,-6,-68,-959,-653,24,658,68,9,-2181]
```

Now first I want to count the number of continuous 3 positive or negative numbers. For that I am using this program:

```
list = [-21,-22,-33,-55,-454,65,48,-516,614,6,2,-64,-64,-87,6,45,87,15,11,03,-34,-6,-68,-959,-653,24,658,68,9,-2181]
counts = []
count = 0

daysCounter = 1
plus_counter = 0
minus_counter = 0
row_counter = 0
answer_counter = 1

for each in list: # for the "dev column"
    if each > 0:
        minus_counter = 0
        plus_counter += 1

        if plus_counter == 3:
            count = answer_counter
            row_counter = answer_counter
            counts.append(count)
            plus_counter = 0
            answer_counter += 1

        else:
            counts.append(0)

    elif each < 0:
        plus_counter = 0
        minus_counter += 1

        if minus_counter == 3:
            count = answer_counter
            row_counter = answer_counter
            counts.append(count)
            minus_counter = 0
            answer_counter += 1
        else:
            counts.append(0)

    row_counter += 1

print counts
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0]
```

This is correct but I want to reset the counter at `%10 == 0`position. Basically, if the list contains 30 elements then I want to count between 0 to 10th element then 11th to 20th then 21th to 30th element. 
desired output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Your list is giving `SyntaxError: invalid token` on 03

Comment: Which counter do you want to reset? There are several of them.

Comment: you say 0 to 10th, thats 11 items, then 11th to 20th thats 10 items. is that correct, or you mean 0 to 9, 10 to 19, 20 to 29 since a list with 30 elements will be indexed from 0 to 29

Comment: Your list as a value with a leading `0` which is a `SyntaxError` because leading zeros in decimal integer literals isn't permitted. You also should never name a variable the same as a built-in type like `list`.

Comment: Do you intend to keep the results or discard them when you *reset the counter*?

Comment: Why do you have `03` in your list? Is that supposed to be `-3`?

Comment: Your question isn’t clear to me. For the first 4 negative numbers, do you wanna count as 1 or 2 sets of contiguous negative numbers? There’re 2 if you slide the window of size 3 by 1 to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didnt make sense to me, you say you want to reset on every module 10 index, yet you then go on to say in a list of 30 elements you want

- 0 to 10 (this is 11 elements)
- 11 to 20 (this is 10 elements)
- 21 to 30 (this is 10 elements)

The total of this would be 31 elements but you said your list has 30 elements. which would be indexed from 0 to 29. So i have made an assumption here that you do mean every 10 elelemts I.E 0 to 9, 10 to 19, 20 to 29. This makes my output out of line with yours but again i can only make an assumption here that you miscounted with your indexes.

```py
nums = [
    -21, -22, -33, -55, -454, 65, 48, -516, 614, 6,
    2, -64, -64, -87, 6, 45, 87, 15, 11, 3,
    -34, -6, -68, -959, -653, 24, 658, 68, 9, -2181
]

nths = 10
sequential_limit = 3
sequential_count = sequential_finds = 0
indexer = sequential_limit - 1
sequential_list = [0 for _ in range(indexer)]
skip = 0

for index, num in enumerate(nums[indexer:], indexer):
    result = 0
    if index % nths == 0:
        sequential_count = sequential_finds = 0
        skip = indexer
    if skip:
        skip -= 1
    else:
        negative = sum(1 for next_num in nums[index - indexer:index + 1] if next_num < 0)
        positive = sum(1 for next_num in nums[index - indexer:index + 1] if next_num >= 0)
        if sequential_limit in (positive, negative):
            sequential_finds += 1
            sequential_count = 0
            skip = indexer
            result = sequential_finds
    sequential_list.append(result)

print(sequential_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0] there is one correction in the desired output, ie., if suppose positive or negative numbers are still continue to occur even after the 3rd time then 2nd sequential_count will start from 3rd element(not from next element). So after this correction desired output will: [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you will have to reset to default values for each period:

```
# other code
for i, each in enumerate(list): # for the "dev column"
    if i % 10 == 0:
        count = 0
        daysCounter = 1
        plus_counter = 0
        minus_counter = 0
        row_counter = 0
        answer_counter = 1
    # remaining code
```

**Note**: You should not name your list as `list`, because you override the built-in.

Comment: I did the exact same thing before but I didn't get the correct answer. It does reset the counter but the numbers are misplaced. Note: the actual problem is a little bit different from this in terms of size of the list (35040 valuesin it )

Answer (score 1):

I think the above desired output you post is not correct

Add this code in the end, This code will reset between 0th to 9th, 10th to 19,20th to 29 elements of a list.

```
list_len = len(counts)
total_multiple = int(list_len/10)

for i in range(1, total_multiple):

    count = 0
    for j in range(10*i, 10*i+10):

        if(counts[j] > 0):
            counts[j] = count
            count += 1
print(counts)
```

It will modify your list and prints

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```